# While Loop with ifs and whiles within stuck loading (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I have the following code, which looks perfectly fine logically, but refuses to do anything, and just gets stuck loading until it times out.

Code:

```
<?php
$name = "billy bobby sharkingflardo herdaderpingtonning";

while (strlen($name) > 17) {
    $nameEx = explode(' ', $name);

    if (strlen($nameEx[0] > 1)) {
        $nameEx[0] = substr($nameEx[0], 0, -(strlen($nameEx[0]) - 1));
    }

    while (count($nameEx) > 2) {
        unset($nameEx[1]);
    }

    if (strlen($nameEx[1] > 15)) {
        substr($nameEx[1], 0, -1);
    }

    $name = implode(' ', $nameEx);
}

echo $name;
?>
```

I don't have much else to say, the code is needed to shorten names which are too long, it does this by reducing the first name to 1 character and removing any middle names, and if the last name alone is too long with remove a character until it is the right length.

Thanks for any help -Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use loops here completely fixed version of your script:

```
<?php
$name = "egergerg ergergerg ergregerg ergergerg dfgeergergergdfsgergergergerg";

if(strlen($name) > 17)
{
    $nameEx = explode(' ', $name);

    if (strlen($nameEx[0]) > 1)
    {
        $nameEx[0] = substr($nameEx[0], 0, -(strlen($nameEx[0]) - 1));
    }

    if(count($nameEx) > 2)
    {
        $nameEx = Array($nameEx[0], $nameEx[count($nameEx)-1]);
    }

    if(strlen($nameEx[1]) > 15)
    {
        $nameEx[1] = substr($nameEx[1], 0, -(strlen($nameEx[1]) - 15));
    }

    $name = implode(' ', $nameEx);
}

echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: Now completely optimized, without loops and quite short.

Comment: I...I... I'm so happy, thank you so much, the code I had was the best I could think of, what you've done I thought should be possible without loops, but didn't know how. Thanks so much.

Comment: I sorted the code a bit this is know the last version. (btw: use it as a function and you can us it everywhere like this: `shortenName($string)` :D)

Comment: @Vereonix: You can simply remove every if except the first `if(strlen($name) > 17)` btw. but it might be a bit dirty. (But it works perfectly.)

Answer (score 2):

I'm only reading it, but I think your line:

```
    while (count($nameEx) > 2) {
        unset($nameEx[1]);
    }
```

is prolly causing it - you unset the second element, not reduce the array. So, I think it just makes an element with keys 0, 2, 3 and never breaks the loop